# How to use connection pool with java,MySQL and Tomcat 6

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling

How can I use Connection pool in Java+MySQL+Tomcat 6?

I've read this article http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/connection_pooling_with_connectorj.html but it is still not quite clear for me.

Where do I use the Connector/J? Do I put it in a static variable? Do I use a SessionListener? Does it need any configuration?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure that you don't use Apache's DBCP. It's a horrible implementation that will actually cause performance problems, not fix them.

Comment: ...so what do you use instead?

Answer (score 7):

You should read the [Tomcat 6 JNDI document](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html). Look for the "JDBC Data Sources" section and it will tell you everything you need to know about pooling connections with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement MySQL connection pooling in Java by using Java's GenericObjectPool that provides robust pooling functionality for arbitrary objects.

See detailed example in this post: [How to set up a MySQL connection pool in Java](http://www.rndblog.com/how-to-set-up-a-mysql-connection-pool-in-java/)

Comment: This isn't correct at all. You should use the built in pooling in Tomcat.